# How to show IPyWidgets in a Jupyter Notebook viewed from Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, ipython, ipywidgets

I am unable to get interactive widgets in VS Code.

In Visual Studio Code - for each output of the cell (in this case outputs are checkboxes) I can manually change the renderer (see screenshot below)

1. If I choose text/plain as the renderer - I obviously get plain text that is useless and uninteractive. (Like in the first output in the screenshot)
2. If I choose the Jupyter IPyWidget Renderer - I get an empty output.

[VS Code - Screenshot of the menu (allows choosing one of the two renderers)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8K5Ht.png)

Here's the code of the problematic cell:

```
# Importing some global variables
# Split message is a list of strings, checkedBoxes is a list of booleans
from helperFunctions import splitMessage, checkedBoxes

# Function to be called every time a checkbox gets toggled - to prove interactivity
def changed(b):
    i = splitMessage.index(b["owner"].description)
    checkedBoxes[i] = b["owner"].value
    print("\n========\n")
    print("{}: switched to {}".format(b["owner"].description, b["owner"].value))

from IPython.display import display
from ipywidgets import Checkbox

checkboxes = []

# Making a list of checkboxes
for msg in splitMessage:
    checkboxes.append(Checkbox(True, description=str(msg)))
    checkedBoxes.append(True)

# Displaying them and connecting them to the function defined above
for chkBx in checkboxes:
    display(chkBx)
    chkBx.observe(changed, names=['value'])
```

When I run this Notebook using the CMD command "jupyter notebook" (which opens in my browser) - the cell works as intended. [Jupyter Lab - The checkboxes present themselves visually properly and are interactive.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMgJK.png)

How to get the same functionality from VS Code?

Comment: Where is your `helperFunctions`?

Comment: @JialeDu it is a custom package that I made. A few of its functions alter the values of`splitMessage` and `checkedBoxes`, however its behaviour doesn't matter considering everything works well in one IDE (Jupyter Lab) and doesn't work in another (VS Code)

Comment: If you don't provide enough code, how do you think we can reproduce your problem? Do I write a helperFunctions myself? And how can I make sure I write the same as you?